# Check membership in a 2d ndarray object in Python

Tags: python, numpy

In python, we usually check if an object is in an array by the `in` keyword, for example, this code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
print(4 in a)
b = np.array(a)
print(4 in a)
```

would give `False, False`.

However, I found that if I use 2d ndarray, the behavior is very weird, the following:

```
a = [[0,0], [0,1]]
print([0,2] in a)
b = np.array(a)
print([0,2] in b)
```

gives `False, True`.

What's going on here?